# WooCommerce Does Not Allow Adding Products To Cart Unless Logged In

Tags: wordpress, hosting, woocommerce

This problem occurred recently - if I am not logged into Wordpress, I am not able to add products to my WooCommerce cart. It redirects to the cart page as it should but shows 'Cart Empty'. Works perfectly when I am logged in as a user in any role. I searched around and found this thread: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-woocommerce-cart-brokennot-adding-products

I've tried changing my session folder with a custom php.ini file but the problem is still persisting. I used Duplicator and set up an instance on my localhost - where it works without issues, so that tells me the problem isn't with the theme or the plugins. What other issues with hosting could be causing this?

Comment: In Settings -> General have you the "Enable guest checkout (no account required)" box ticked?

Comment: I already did that. It wasn't the problem. Turns out the problem was caused by the use of the Duplicator plugin. When I duplicated the site, I did not set 'http://' in front of the domain name and this is the error that resulted. Problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

For me the error was caused by Rackspace's "Varnish" script. it's a server-side caching tool that they use. I don't have more details than than. but once I alerted Rackspace, they fixed it pretty fast.