# WooCommerce not adding to Cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

After being a lurker for years on Stack Overflow this is my first question because I can't seem to find an answer - wish me luck :)

I've just set a new site live that I used the Duplicator plugin to copy from my local install, but for some reason WooCommerce won't add products to the cart. I found this question but my problem may not be related to the Duplicator plugin.
[WooCommerce Does Not Allow Adding Products To Cart Unless Logged In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570981/woocommerce-does-not-allow-adding-products-to-cart-unless-logged-in/23760435)

I'm also having trouble with the WP embedded media player and the tabs on the product page which I think may all be related....

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Ps, the site is live in case you want to take a look at it: http://waltkeys.com/shop

Also, I am using the most recent version of WooCommerce, Harmony by Elegant themes and very minimal plugins - not sure which could be conflicting

Comment: Maybe providing more detail (for instance source code or descriptive errors) would help other users trying to answer the question. Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also related: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/851811).

Comment: Thanks @XaviLópez but there aren't any errors even with WP Debug on and nothing I can tell in the Chrome dev console either except for "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead." So really not sure what else I can really provide....

Comment: For some reason I can't comment on anything else until I've reached 10 comments...

Comment: Do these comments count? Hopefully!